# How to like on behalf of the user - Facebook Workplace API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

While working with the [Facebook Workplace API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference) liking an object (post, comment, photo..etc) can be done by passing the Admin Access Token, I'm trying to figure out how to do it on behalf on the user for a feed / comment posted into a group.

The docs mention getting the Page Access Token to perform this action but a Group doesn't have an Access Token & doesn't really solve what I'm going for anyway.

I've tried getting the User Impersonation Token from the API using the Admin Token but posting to the likes graph endpoint results in a publishing error.

```
POST /https://graph.facebook.com/{COMMENT-ID or POST-ID}/likes
HEADERS: Authorization Bearer "{IMPERSONATION-TOKEN}"
```

Error Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Publishing likes through the API is only available for page access tokens",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "CGpXtFWrwiA"
  }
}
```

Again this works fine using the Admin App Access Token but not on behalf of the user. Also a group doesn't have an access token unlike a regular FB Page.

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: Outside of Workplace, liking stuff in the name of a user is not possible any more, Facebook has removed that quite a while ago. Is there _any_ indication in the Workplace documentation, that it is different there?

Comment: Not that I could see unfortunately, liking using the page token / admin app token works but just not on-behalf of the user.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, the case is that [the `impersonation_token` is deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/graph-api/#memberaccesstoken) and related permissioning is no longer available to integrations.